# Extract words from continous strings

Tags: python, algorithm, nltk, text-mining

I have inputs:

```
callme
senditnow
runningcar
```

how can i extract words like call me,send it now, running car.Is there any library in python to do that using some dictionary.

Comment: You are fixing this on the wrong side. The "writer" who created this file should add delimiters to your text. Fixing this with approaches like a dictionary would be a nightmare.

Comment: I have retagged to algorithm, since regex is certainly not a solution here, since regex doesn't know English to separate the text. You certainly need some NLP algorithm + dictionary to do this.

Comment: @HelloWorld That may be so, but this is an everyday problem for languages which do not mark word boundaries, and they manage to solve it to at least reasonable satisfaction.

Comment: @tripleee: If we talk about automata theory I agree, but for a natural language I can't think of a real world problem. Do you have an example? One solution could be an inserted [ZERO WIDTH SPACE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm) to improve text processing.

Comment: @HelloWorld CJK languages are obvious examples. Historically, pretty much every language there is. The space is a relatively recent innovation in writing.

Comment: Closer to home, finding word boundaries in English-language URLs is a problem I have seen people try to solve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know about proper ways to do it, but there are ways to cheat !

It was an algorithm exercise problem I solved at university, where you have a string with no spaces (e.g. `thesearethereasons`) and you're trying to get back the words.

The trick was trying to turn the problem into a graph (Directed Acyclic Graph) : 
You need a function to check if a word exists in dictionnary (I used  `/usr/share/dict/words` parsed with `grep` at the time), and then try all combination of words that way. Store the words and start/end indices.

```
These (0,4)
The (0,2)
Sea (3,5)
[...]
```

You then just need to turn these into a graph by making links between end of one word and beginning of other :

```
*--+The----Sea-------(no more words there)
   |
   +-These---Are+----The+-------Reason (not end)
                |       +----Reasons [String end]   <== Solution
                |
                +----There---A---Sons [String end]  <== False Positive
```

Now you have a word graph, just follow it (DFS) to the end. Any path that ends with the string's end represent words =)

As you can imagine, several word combinations can do the trick, giving you back a series of "plausible sentences". Not a perfect solution then

Comment: Your graph is incomplete; it lacks the obvious false positive "... there a sons".

Comment: Thanks for reminding me : I HATED that false positive when implementing the solution

Answer (score 3):

Peter Norvig solves this exact problem in his chapter of the book [Beautiful Data](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596157128.do) (Segaran and Hammerbacher, 2009).

[Here](http://norvig.com/ngrams/ch14.pdf) is the chapter in question.

What you want to do is to find a segmentation such that the product of probabilities for each word gives the highest score. In doing so, you avoid producing a non-word (which should have near-zero probability) and you likely choose the correct segmentation when many are possible.

This is a safer way to do it than to go with the graph method, since it will reject possible but improbable elements.

(How would you segment "speedofart" or "expertsexchange"?)

In short, the method goes as follow:

1. Define a probabilistic model
2. Enumerate possible candidates
3. Choose the most probable word segmentation

You define the model once, and run steps 2 and 3 for every string you want to segment. Steps 2 and 3 run with complexity O(n**2), where n is length of the string to segment.

Everything is explained in great detail in the links I gave you, plus you get the Python code to implement all of it!

Comment: I just wanted to add: you could make the segmentation model even stronger if you also computed the probability of each segment to be right next to each other, ie computing the bigram probability for each pair of words.  For that you would need a bigram probability model, built using a technique similar to the unigram model estimation. This way you would be very likely to prevent selection of sequences like the "There a sons" false positive in Jiby's answer.